# How to replace a repeated string between delimiters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace a sequence of text inside a delimiter, exactly the number of times it occurs. E.g. I have a text like this:

```
"Cow says &moo;RGH but also &moo;moo;moo;RGH and &moo;moo;moo;moo;moo;RGH too but it doesn't moo; bah!"
```

I want to replace each "moo;" between "&" and "RGH" with an "A", so I expect that:

```
"Cow says &ARGH but also &AAARGH and &AAAAARGH but it doesn't moo; bah!"
```

In other words, I have to replace each "moo;" between "&" and "RGH" with an "A". I have to replace it via javascript on the whole text using a single regexp (if possible)
I did a lot of attempts, e.g.:

```
var a="Cow says &moo;RGH but also &moo;moo;moo;RGH and &moo;moo;moo;moo;moo;RGH but it doesn't moo; bah!"
a=a.replace(/(?<=&)((moo;)\1?)+RGH/g,"A");
// a=a.replace(/&(moo;)+RGH/g,"A")
// a=a.replace(/&(?=moo;)\1RGH/g,"A"
console.log(a);
```

but without evident success.
The idea is that each "moo;" must be replaced with "A" only if present along with other "moo;"s between a "&" and "RGH"

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Does the number of `A`'s give you any insight after the replacement or is it just a  exercise ?

Comment: Nope, it's just an example. My application is quite more complex since it involves a great (random) number of occurrences...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `(moo;)*` into the lookbehind and lookahead assertion. That way the regex will match all moos between `&` and `RGH`:

```js
var a="Cow says &moo;RGH but also &moo;moo;moo;RGH and &moo;moo;moo;moo;moo;RGH but it doesn't moo; bah!"
a=a.replace(/(?<=&(moo;)*)moo;(?=(moo;)*RGH)/g, 'A');
console.log(a);
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000000">

let a = "Cow says &moo;RGH but also &moo;moo;moo;RGH and &moo;moo;moo;moo;moo;RGH too but it doesn't moo; bah!";

// @benchmark Unmitigated
a.replace(/(?<=&)(moo;)+(?=RGH)/g, m => 'A'.repeat(m.length / 4));

// @benchmark Alexander
a.replace(/(?<=&(moo;)*)(moo;)(?=(moo;)*RGH)/g, 'A');

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this one does exactly what I was looking for. 
(Incidentally... a really cute benchmark tool, thanks for letting me know it)

Answer (score 3):

You can also match all the consecutive sequences of `moo;` and pass a callback to `String#replace` that replaces each sequence based on its length.

```js
let str = "Cow says &moo;RGH but also &moo;moo;moo;RGH and &moo;moo;moo;moo;moo;RGH too but it doesn't moo; bah!";
let res = str.replace(/(?<=&)(moo;)+(?=RGH)/g, m => 'A'.repeat(m.length / 4));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is a good answer too.

Comment: Nice idea, but it depends on the "moo;" length.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to replace each occurrence of *"moo;"*, you'll want to only match the singular occurrence, and not a sequence.

You can use the *look-around* syntax to assert valid occurrences of *"moo;"*

```
(?<=&|moo;)moo;(?=RGH|moo;)
```

```js
var string = 'Cow says &moo;RGH but also &moo;moo;moo;RGH and &moo;moo;moo;moo;moo;RGH too but it doesn\'t moo; bah!'
string = string.replace(/(?<=&|moo;)moo;(?=RGH|moo;)/g, 'A')

console.log(string)
```

Comment: @Sampisa Except this doesn't work. It replaces the `"moo;"` in the middle for the input `"moo;moo;moo;"` even there's no `&` or `RGH`. It's "faster" because it doesn't do those checks.

Comment: @Unmitigated are you sure? I tried with jsfiddle (I used # instead than &) and it works properly
https://jsfiddle.net/sampisa/zdyopu17/1/
AARGH you are right :) Thanks!

Comment: @Sampisa Yes, I updated your example to demonstrate the issue (https://jsfiddle.net/gfy4j2u0/). Note the "moo;Amoo;" in the result.